# Apple Push Notification - Change default sound

Tags: apple-push-notifications

In creating a notification payload for Apple Push Notification, I use `default` as `sound`. What are other values I can pass to `sound`?

```
 {
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "You got a push!",
        "badge" : 1,
        "sound" : "default"
      },
    "acme1" : "bar",
    "acme2" : 42
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From APNs' website…

> The name of a sound file in the application bundle. The sound in this file is played as an alert. If the sound file doesn’t exist or default is specified as the value, the default alert sound is played. The audio must be in one of the audio data formats that are compatible with system sounds; see “Preparing Custom Alert Sounds” for details.

And the link is here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW6

Comment: Honest answer is "I don't know" :p

Comment: And I don't think it is possible.

Comment: The link provided returns a "404"